# What is Package/Identity/Name and what does it correspond to?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps, windows-10-mobile, windows-phone-store

Few days ago I submited my first WP 8.1 app on the Windows phone store (it's in the certification stage). Unfortunately, I'm having a bit of a trouble with correct IDs.

In my Microsoft Developer Dashboard, when I go to the "manage application", I have something like this (not exactly like this, but in this format):

**Package/Identity/Name:    11111Keran.zzzzzxxxxxccccccc**

Now, in my Package.appxmanifest file I am forced to put this as an Identity Name:

Identity Name="11111Keran.zzzzzxxxxxccccccc" etc...>

Is this the Application ID? Normally the application ID is a GUID, but I don't have it anywhere stored in any configuration file. I was only able to retrie it using this code:

**var appId = Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentApp.AppId;**
And it returns me some GUID.

The problem starts when I try to extract the data from the Isolated Storage of my app using this script:

**cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.1\Tools\IsolatedStorageExplorerTool"
ISETool.exe ts de [MYAPPGUID] C:\Isolated**

When I provide the GUID that I got from the code, it says the app is not installed, when I provide the identity name (11111Keran.zzzzzxxxxxccccccc) it says that it's not a GUID.

Not to mention I now completely don't know what should I put in the ad configuration for the Microsoft Adveristing in Application ID - should it be the GUID I receive, or the 11111Keran.zzzzzxxxxxccccccc, or will it come once my app is certified? At the moment ads are completely not showing and the code doesn't even go to the errors (I'm using AdMediator control), just black box with nothing in it.

It's a real mess and I cannot find a good tutorial anywhere, so any help and tips will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Package Name** is the name of your package. It's unique and identifies your package in user's system. When you create a new project, Visual Studio assigns some GUID to use it as your package's name. But when you associate your app with the Store and choose one of your reserved app names, VS updates Package Name to some more readable value, usually involving a short string of letters and numbers combined with name of the app. If you not going to deploy your app to Windows Store, you can change this value to anything you want.

As far as I know, IsolatedStorageExplorerTool [only supports](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh286408(v=vs.105).aspx) Windows Phone 8.0, that's probably why you have problems with your 8.1 app. If you want to explore or modify your WP 8.1 local storage, best tool for this is [IsoStoreSpy](https://isostorespy.codeplex.com/) . Try it out!

Comment: Thank you, that really cleared up a lot! I will try out the tool. 

I think I have the ads configured nicely now, I will test it once my app gets certified (for some reason it crashes for Microsoft QAs on start and the only feedback I got from them is "App crashes on start, steps to reproduce: 1. Run app, 2. Notice it doesn't work"... 

However I cannot reproduce it.. Still I did some fixes and I'll see if the second submission fixed the problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what @Andrey said, I want to add something for your third question.

> At the moment ads are completely not showing and the code doesn't even
>   go to the errors (I'm using AdMediator control)

Actually for AdControl and Interstitial Ads, you need the Application ID and Ad unit ID.
In the Dashboard, Click Monetize with ads:
[image]

After you find this column and click Show options

[image]

You will be able to create ad unit, you can get Application ID and Ad unit ID.
In your VS project, please replace them with the test ones.

However about Admediator control,  these parameters are automatically filled in for you when you submit your app package, based on the contents of your app, so you do not need to add the Application ID and Ad unit ID by yourself. 
For more information, please try to refer to the following article:
[Selecting and managing your ad networks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn864356.aspx%20.)

Here is the procedure to add an Admediator ad:
First please download
[Microsoft Store Advertising SDK for Windows and Windows Phone 8.x.](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bb4b3020-9b56-4e81-a314-e40cff00fb52)
Then add reference
[image]

After that  Add connected service

Choose Ad mediator then click Configure Select Ad networks
[image]

Then drag a AdMediatorControl to the main page.

```
   <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <WindowsPhone81:AdMediatorControl x:Name="AdMediator" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="304" Id="AdMediator-Id-269CB8A1-6751-4872-9F35-188DA32B9A2C" Margin="59,47,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="306"/>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="909,163,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
   </Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you very much as well. I think I cleaned up everything regarding the IDs. Some example ads are showing in my debug. Once my app gets to the store I will see if it works, thanks again.